# showing and handling a fyne window in golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to make this script able to show the GUI (drawMessage) every time the funcion initConnection receive a command from the server side
as you can see this script calls the drawMessage() from the func initConnection() when receiving the command "ShowWindow" this code works fine only
at the first time receiving the command after the first time and closing the GUI when i try to send the command again no Window pops up
how can make it responsive at every time receiving the command?

```
package main

import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/canvas"
    "fyne.io/fyne/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
)

var done = make(chan struct{})

func initConnection(receivedCommand string) {
    switch receivedCommand {
    case "ShowWindow":
        done <- struct{}{}
    }
}
func main() {

    go initConnection()

    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            DrawMessage()
        }
    }
}

func DrawMessage() {
    myApp := app.New()
    myWindow := myApp.NewWindow("New GUI")
    image := canvas.NewImageFromFile("message.png")
    image.FillMode = canvas.ImageFillOriginal
    content := container.NewVBox(container.NewCenter(image))
    myWindow.SetContent(content)
    myWindow.ShowAndRun()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in your previous question ([Processing function in background while GUI is shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77194490/processing-function-in-background-while-gui-is-shown/77200622?noredirect=1#comment136098286_77200622)) you should separate the App.Run from Window.Show…
You the running application keeps it from exiting, but you can show the window later on than starting the Fyne app.

Comment: can you please give me an example ?

Comment: It’s covered in the docs at https://developer.fyne.io/started/windows